# Logs Insights query - group by with pivot

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a CloudWatch log stream that contains structured records like the following:

| type | env |
| --- | --- |
| type1 | dev |
| type1 | prod |
| type2 | dev |

I'd like to query the counts of each type by the env (to graph them)

Something equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN env = 'dev' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dev, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN env = 'prod' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS prod 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY type
```

I've written the following query:

```
fields @timestamp, record.type as type, record.env as env
| stats count(env="dev") as dev, count(env="prod") as prod by type
```

expecting to get the following result:

| type | dev | prod |
| --- | --- | --- |
| type1 | 1 | 1 |
| type2 | 1 | 0 |

But unfortunately, I'm getting the same count for both columns regardless of the applied filter inside the `count()`  as follows:

[image]

How can I achieve the output I need

#### Note

I can do the following query to get the results grouped by each `env`:

```
fields @timestamp, record.type as type, record.env as env
| stats count(*) by type, env
```

I'll get :

| type | env | count() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| type1 | dev | 1 |
| type1 | prod | 1 |
| type2 | dev | 1 |

But I need the pivoted version

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple case, i.e. when

- only `count` or `sum(field)` is required
- **and** number of options is limited (e.g. dev,beta,gamma,prod)

you can do following

```
fields record.type as type, record.docsCount as docsCount
| fields (record.env="dev") as IsDev, (record.env="prod") as isProd
| stats 
   sum(isDev) as devEntries, 
   sum(isDev * docsCount) as devDocsCount,
   sum(isProd) as prodEntries, 
   sum(isProd * docsCount) as prodDocsCount 
  by type
```

Note, approach above does not work for the cases when you need statistics like `avg`, `stddev` etc.

`avg(isDev * docsCount)` will produce zeroes for the `prod` rows, and those zeroes will impact output.